# Eevee glass not working at certain angles

Tags: eevee-render-engine, glass, reflection

I'm trying to get glass to look realistic in eevee. I'm getting this weird error when I move the angle of the camera. Any help would be great thanks!

Gif of glass error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVYVt.jpg

Link to blender file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18KG3m_MMqHvbV7azvqyHwy5V8gl_JxNz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please attach your blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and insert video as gif into your question via Edit. Thank you

Comment: BTW does this answered your Q https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173288/window-glass-material-eevee?answertab=votes#tab-top ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called 'Edge Fading' under 'Screen Space Reflections' settings in Render Settings. Try making it 0. That should most likely do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the glass down half way to see what it looks like without glass there and realized the problem. If I just reduce the IOR to 1 then it fixes the problem. Guess this is a good example of the limitations of eevee